# Plain text display in MS OneNote

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, microsoft-onenote

I have an issue with displaying plain text in Microsoft OneNote. If I paste the text below (the screen taken in notepad++)

[image]

into OneNote as Keep Text Only, I completely lose the formatting (note, there are just spaces, no tabs or any other fancy chars).

[image]

Moreover, if I paste the same text from OneNote back to notepad++ the formatting is fine again. So, what's wrong with OneNote, are there any settings to fix this behaviour?

Comment: [See if importing it works](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a font thing, here is the solution
http://www.office-forums.com/threads/problem-with-pasting-ascii-art-in-to-onenote.78083/
I have to apply a monospace font (such as Courier New) to the text.

Comment: Or apply the 'Code' style